# Dynamic tabs in TabView nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

Is it possible to create tabs dynamically for a tabview in nativescript?

The following example is in the documentation of nativescript

```
<TabView selectedIndex="0"  (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'NativeScript'}">
        <Label text="NativeScript" class="m-15 h2 text-left" color="blue"></Label>
        <ScrollView>
            <Label [text]="content" textWrap="true" class="m-15"></Label>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Icon'}">
        <Image class="m-t-30 m-b-15" src="res://icon" width="80" height="80"></Image>
        <Label text="NativeScript" textWrap="true" class="h2 m-x-auto" color="blue"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

and it does not allow me to use the ng for since the StackLayout element already has a directive that starts with *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can ! use `*ngFor`

```
<TabView>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabList">
       <StackLayout *tabItem="tab">
                .....
       </StackLayout>
    </ng-container>
</TabView>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you said but the view of tab 1 and tab 2 are not being generated, but if I browse among the other tabs and return to the first ones already appear, any suggestions?

Comment: I run into the same issue ! y i don't have a correct answer but what worked for me is my data was pulled of from service (=>subscribe) but when i shift to database promise it worked and what's killing me it's i did'nt find anything about "TabView items dynamic content" i've been googling since 2 day when i run into you question

Comment: It's still happening for me. Have some of you found and answer...?